# Submenu not showing and search menu on same line

Tags: html, css, menu, z-index, submenu

I am currently installing a new website with a "max mega menu". The problem is, I can't get the submenu to show. I've tried with different z-index but I can't get it to work.

The second problem is, that the search menu is displaying on a new line. I want it on the same height as the main menu. How can i manage that?

This is the website: [Link](http://new.4progress.ch/)

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default submenus are set as display none and when mouse hover its set as display block but in your css you are set one more css as below as visibility hidden so just remove this

```
#mega-menu-wrap-main_menu #mega-menu-main_menu li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-     sub-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;// just remove this
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have in css:
`visibility: hidden;` set. Becouse of that elements of menu is invisible

```
    #mega-menu-wrap-main_menu #mega-menu-main_menu li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-sub-menu
     {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

Just change it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve search menu new line problem set `float: left` to `#mega-menu-wrap-main_menu`

```
#mega-menu-wrap-main_menu {
    float: left;
}
```